# SQLite: ON DELETE CASCADE is not working right

Tags: sqlite

I tried very often and looked also on the other forum posts, but they didn't help me.
This is my problem: I create Tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Parent
    (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     Name STRING);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Child
    (Id INTEGER,
     Name STRING,
     ParentId INTEGER,
     PRIMARY KEY (Id, ParentId)
     FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES Parent (ParentId) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

After that I insert this:

```
INSERT INTO Parent (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'Michael');
INSERT INTO Child (Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES (1, 'Paul', 1);
```

Alright! We have now in each table a row with a parent and a child. Now I want to delete the parent:

```
DELETE FROM Parent WHERE Id = 1;
```

What is happening? The row in the table 'Parent' is not there anymore, but the row in the table 'Child' is still there, even if I said: 'ON DELETE CASCADE'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Foreign key constraints are not active by default. You must enable them with the following command, once per database session :

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

From [Official Doc](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) :

> ### 2. Enabling Foreign Key Support
>
> Assuming the library is compiled with foreign key constraints enabled,
>   it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the
>   PRAGMA foreign_keys command. For example:
>
> ```
> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
> ```
>
> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards
>   compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database
>   connection.

Comment: Where I need it, it works - thanks! But: In this example I get always foreign key mismatch. How to fix this?

Comment: you are missing a comma before the FOREIGN KEY declaration

Comment: Biggest fail of my live, but still foreign key mismatch

Comment: @Gaem Your parent table doesn't have a ParentId column.

Comment: Nope... the mistake was: I forgot to add PRIMARY KEY in the table 'Parent'